# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'model' of undefined

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a special problem with a callback method and local variable:

```
 export class Test {

   model: Article;

   onKeyEnter(value: string) {
    this.model.maktx = "Test1";

    //This is not working
    this.find(value);

    // Direct call is working
    //this.readSuccessCallback(null, null);
  }

  find(nr) {

    [..other stuff]

    OData.read(request, this.readSuccessCallback, this.errorCallback);
  }

   readSuccessCallback(data, response) {  
     this.model.maktx = "Test2";
  }
}
```

The `"Test2"` value is set correctly when I call `readSuccessCallback` direct from `onKeyEnter`

If the `readSuccessCallback` method is called from the `OData.read` 
(SAP Kapsel 3rd Party) an exception occured:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'model' of undefined.

Has anyone got an idea what is happening? I don't know exactly what `OData.read` is doing but it seems that I am not coming back to where I was leaving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
OData.read(request, this.readSuccessCallback.bind(this), this.errorCallback.bind(this));
```

Comment: Hi yurzui, thanks for your answer. Your solution is working!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your `readSuccessCallback` is called, but that `this` has become `undefined`. This may be the case when you are working in strict mode (which I believe is the default mode from 1.8 up).

I can't test this here, but define your callback like so:

```
public readSuccessCallback(data, response) = (data, response) => {
  this.model.maktx = "Test3";
}
```

which should lead `this` to point to your actual instance.

Comment: Hi Roy, thanks for your answer. This syntax is not working. After the ) is { or ; expected.